# How can i get file path on a file object in a form with jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, upload, filepath

I need to file name and file path when i select a file for upload with a file object in form.
It can be use with javascript or jquery i think
because i need to use it on browser.

I tried this ways 
This is my file object id and name : Upload1

```
$("#Upload1").val();
$('#Upload1').attr("value");
document.getElementById("Upload1").files[0].name;
this.Upload1.value;
```

It returns "C:\fakepath\example.gdb"
or
"example.gdb"

but i need to original path of file. 
and it should not be temporary file and path 
for example : $_FILES["Upload1"]["tmp_name"]

Please help...
Thanks.

Comment: Why exactly do you need the file path? There isn't a whole lot you could do with it. The browser doesn't allow access to this information.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't get file path - *refer to w3 language reference*

> The input element with a type attribute whose value is "file"
>   represents a list of file items, each consisting of a file name, a
>   file type, and a file body (the contents of the file)

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html